# Android: Samsung Galaxy S II Navigation Bar being calculated

Tags: android, navbar, galaxy

I have an Android Samsung Galaxy S II device that I'm testing my app with.  In my app, I check whether the navigation bar is taking up any space on the screen using the following code:

```
Resources resources = context.getResources();
int resourceId = resources.getIdentifier("navigation_bar_height", "dimen", "android");
if (resourceId > 0) {
    return resources.getDimensionPixelSize(resourceId);
}
return 0;
```

I do this so I can set appropriate margins for other devices.  But for the Samsung Galaxy S II, the navigation bar is not actually on screen (there are a row of capacitive buttons below the screen).  However, when I calculate the navbarheight, I get a non-zero value (72).

Can someone explain to me why it is returning this value?

Answer (score 1):

that's because the dimension resource `navigation_bar_height` exists regardless of device.

you have to check the device API level and if have hardware buttons using `Build.VERSION.SDK_INT` and [hasPermanentMenuKey](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewConfiguration.html#hasPermanentMenuKey%28%29)